# How to set a proxy to a socket?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, proxy, websocket

I want to use a proxy in a socket, just like I use a proxy in a webclient here:

```
using(Webclient wb = new Webclient()
{
   wb.Proxy = new WebProxy();
}
```

I want to use a webproxy here:

```
public void Connect()
{
    this.socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    this.socket.Connect(this.whatsHost, this.whatsPort);

    this.socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, this.recvTimeout);
    this.socket.ReceiveBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;

    // this.socket.SendBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;

    if (!this.socket.Connected)
        throw new ConnectionException("Cannot connect");
}
```

Is there a way to use a proxy in a socket ?

Answer (score 0):

A web proxy is ... that, a web thing. A socket is a raw TCP connection, a web connection uses a socket internally. When you use a proxy, the inherent socket will connect to the proxy endpoint, and through the application protocol, the web client will indicate where it wants to connect.

Answering your question ... no. Sockets are TCP connections, and you have to provide the final endpoint you want to connect. Proxies are an application level thing.